# Concat string inside webpack.DefinePlugin

Tags: node.js, webpack

I'm using the webpack.DefinePlugin, below is what I have

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'REST_URL': REST_URL[nodeEnv],
  'process.env': {
    NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(nodeEnv)
  }
})
```

I want to concat a string after `REST_URL[nodeEnv]` I have tried multiple ways like

```
'REST_URL': REST_URL[nodeEnv] + "/service"
'REST_URL': REST_URL[nodeEnv] + '/service'
'REST_URL': REST_URL[nodeEnv].concat('/service')
```

All of them methods I tried above result in an error. What is the proper way to concat a string inside the webpack.DefinePlugin plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the proper answer but have you tried `${REST_URL[nodeEnv]}/service`

I would comment but I lack the reputation =/